# How to push data to a multidimensional array?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, reference

I want to create 10 one dimensional arrays , and put these 10 one dimensional arrays to another one dimensional array , and store some data to some specific index of array .

but the output what I expect should be

```
expect output         real output
    0                      1
    1                      1
    0                      1
    3                      1
    0                      1
    5                      1
    0                      1
    7                      1
    0                      1
    0                      1
```

here is my code

```
@Hits = ();

# Create 10 one dimension array
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++)
{
    @Space = ();
    push(@Hits,\@Space);
}

# Store some data to some index
push(@{$Hits[1]},1);
push(@{$Hits[3]},3);
push(@{$Hits[5]},5);
push(@{$Hits[7]},7);

# print the first element of 10 arrays
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++)
{
    print $Hits[$i]->[0];
    print "\n";
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Problem is that you aren't properly declaring your variables. For every script, you should

```perl
use strict; use warnings;
```

This disallows common error sources, warns about iffy stuff, and forces you to properly declare all your variables.

By default, all undeclared variables are considered *global*. Therefore, in

```
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++)
{
    @Space = ();
    push(@Hits,\@Space);
}
```

the `@Space` refers to the same array in each iteration. Ergo, all ten entries in `@Hits` are a reference to the same array. Let's inspect what `@Hits` actually is. We can do so with `Data::Dumper` or the `Data::Dump` module (the latter usually produces prettier output):

```
use Data::Dump;  # use Data::Dumper;
dd \@Hits;       # print Dumper \@Hits;
```

We get with `Data::Dumper` (easier to understand):

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            3,
            5,
            7
          ],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0],
          $VAR1->[0]
        ];
```

---

So I said the solution would be declaring your variables. Specifically, we want *lexical variables*. These variables are only visible *inside* the block where they are declared. This makes reasoning about code much easier. We can declare a lexical variable like so:

```
my $foo = 123;
```

When we have a loop like

```
my @Hits;
for my $i  (0 .. 9) {
  my @Space;
  push @Hits, \@Space;
}
```

then each time the `my` is executed, we get a *new* `@Space`. Oh, and I have used a foreach-loop, that iterates over the range `0 .. 9` with the (lexical) `$i` variable. I find this easier to understand than the C-style loops you used.

Because every element in `@Hits` now is a *different* arrayref, we get the expected data structure. As `Data::Dump` output:

```
[[], [1], [], [3], [], [5], [], [7], [], []]
```

When we now execute your loop that prints out the first value of each sub-array, then you may be suprised by the empty lines in between the numebers. This is because e.g. the first arrayref does not have an entry at index `0`, and therefore returns the special `undef` value. When used as a string, this is the empty string. If you followed my advice and did the `use warnings`, you also get a message that you are printing an uninitialized value.

We can solve this by testing for definedness, and providing a zero otherwise. Since perl5 v10, we can use the defined-or operator `//` for this (on earlier perls, the `||` logical or has to do).

```
for my $i (0 .. 9) {
  my $value = $Hits[$i][0] // 0;
  print "$value\n";
}
```

There are a few other bits we can improve:

- We don't have to manually create the `@Space` arrays; Perl does this behind the scenes when you *dereference* an array entry like `@{ $Hits[$i] }`. This is called *autovivification*.
- Not only can we iterate over ranges, but also over arrays. This is much better than hardcoding indices.
- Since v10, you can use the `say` feature. The `say` function is exactly like `print` but appends a newline at the end.

Here is how I'd have written that code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; use feature 'say';

my @Hits;

for my $i (1, 3, 5, 7) {
  push @{ $Hits[$i] }, $i;
}

for my $arrayref (@Hits) {
  say $arrayref->[0] // 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
0
3
0
5
0
7
```

(Note that we never initialized values at positions 8 and 9, so they are not shown. We could amend this by iterating over the *slice* `@Hits[0 .. 9]`.)

Answer (score 1):

I change your code like following:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
@Hits = ();

push(@{$Hits[1]},1);
push(@{$Hits[3]},3);
push(@{$Hits[5]},5);
push(@{$Hits[7]},7);

#print the content of
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++)
{
    if (defined ($Hits[$i])) {
        print "$Hits[$i][0]\n";
    } else {
        print "0\n";
    }
}
```

It's incorrect to give the ref of @space to @Hits and that makes the wrong result. It's not necessary to initial @Hits in perl.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -e "use Data::Dump; @sf=(); push @{$sf[0]},"0"; push @{$sf[1]},"1"; dd \@sf;"
[[0], [1]]
```

or

```
perl -e "use Data::Dump; @sf=(); push @sf,["0"]; push @sf,["1"]; dd \@sf;"
[[0], [1]]
```